# Create a node programmatically then reference an existing node to that node?

Tags: nodes

I'm using Drupal 7 and trying to create a node programmatically. Once the node has been created I would like to reference it to an existing node

I'm creating a node programmatically like below

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = $type;
$node->title = $title;
$node->uid = $user->uid;
node_object_prepare($node);
//set field values
node_save($node);
```

Which works.

I would then like to update an existing node to reference the newly-created node.
I basically load the existing node, get the node id from the newly created node and update the reference field, like below

```
$node2 = node_load($node2);

$node2->field_reference['und'][0] = array(
  'target_id' => $node,
  'target_type' => 'node',
);

node_save($node2);

drupal_goto("node/$node->nid");
```

I get two errors when I add the second part to the code 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$nid in node_tokens()
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in DatabaseStatementBase->execute()

The first part works, the second does not. I'm getting the id of $node2 through tokens.

How can I make this work?

Comment: `$node2` is a node object or node ID?

Comment: When you are loading node2, shouldn't it be $node2= node_load($node2->nid); ? I see $node2 = node_load($node2);. Also the 'target_id' is $node or $node->nid ?

Comment: If you have valid answers why not post an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1):

As for the second part, you need to pass node ID or array of node IDs to [`node_load`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) function first argument.

Your code should look like the following:

```
$node2 = node_load($nid); // pass integer node ID or array of integers 

$node2->field_reference['und'][0] = array(
  'target_id' => $node->nid, // pass integer node ID not node object
);

node_save($node2);

drupal_goto("node/{$node->nid}");
```

Comment: your answer looks fine and also working in my case. I am using 'nid' in place of 'target_id', rest depends on what kind of values this reference field contains.

Comment: References module uses `nid`, Entity Reference `target_id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal 7, I suggest to use `entity_type`, so you can easly create nodes by fetching a type of entity you have to add[here in your case it is **node** type]. Easy way and much suitable for your requirement.

If you are interested, look at my answer to the question [Fetching more than id's of an entity using EntityFieldQuery](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) on Drupal Answers. Once if you have created an `etity_type`, then it is up to you. You are always welcome to the world of entities.

Thank you.